# What are the digits in an ObjC method type encoding string?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime, method-signature

I'm reading
Apple's [article about Objective-C runtime type encoding strings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html)
and some methods have numbers in their type strings.

What do the numbers in `v12@0:4@8` mean?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This looks like an encoding of a setter method like this:

```
- (void) setSomething:(id) anObject
```

To break it down:

- `v` means void return type
- `12` means the size of the argument frame (12 bytes)
- `@0` means that there is an Objective-C object type at byte offset 0 of the argument frame (this is the implicit `self` object in each Objective-C method)
- `:4` means that there is a selector at byte offset 4 (this is the implicit `_cmd` in every method, which is the selector that was used to invoke the method).
- `@8` means that there is another Objective-C object type at byte offset 8.

Comment: So the first number is the argument frame size, and others are offsets...thanks!

Comment: Note for future readers: [bbum says the offset numbers are meaningless at this point](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11527925/603977).

Comment: . 12 is not the size of the argument frame, which becomes more clear if you see my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41502199/deciphering-objc-method-description-in-swift-conversion-decoding-questions)