# How to decipher "objc_method_description" from protocol method description list?

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c-runtime

I have some Swift 3 code to decode an iOS Objective-C protocol (which has a Swift counterpart). After concluding Swift 3 reflection was not developed enough to accomplish what I needed, I stumbled on the objc runtime method `protocol_copyMethodDescriptionList()`, which returns an array of the following C structs:

```
struct objc_method_description
     SEL name;
     char *types;
};
```

The code fetches a list of protocol selector names, but not sure what's being returned in the `type` field. I'm confused about how to properly decode `objc_method_description.type` values.

What I'm getting in the the `type` fields are in a cryptic format, for example, `"B48@0:8@16{_NSRange=QQ}24@40"` At first I thought it was a problem in how I was converting C strings, but after some study, I suspect it actually *is* an encoding of the parameters, similar how Java's JVM passes around method signatures. But I still have no reference by which to decode it.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var noteView : UITextView!

    func decodeProto() {
        var methodCount : UInt32 = 1
        if let methodList = protocol_copyMethodDescriptionList(UITextViewDelegate.self,
                  false, true,  UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>(&methodCount)) {
            for i in 0..<Int(methodCount) {
                let methodDesc = methodList[i];
                let name = methodDesc.name
                let types = String(validatingUTF8: methodDesc.types)
                print("\(name) \(types)")
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        decodeProto()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

The output of that in the XCode console is:

> <sup>Optional(`textViewDidBeginEditing:`) Optional("v24@0:8@16")</sup>
>   <sup>Optional(`textViewDidEndEditing:`) Optional("v24@0:8@16")</sup>
>   <sup>Optional(`textViewShouldBeginEditing:`) Optional("B24@0:8@16")</sup>
>   <sup>Optional(`textViewShouldEndEditing:`) Optional("B24@0:8@16")</sup>
>   <sup>Optional(`textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:`) Optional("B48@0:8@16{_NSRange=QQ}24@40")</sup>
>   <sup>Optional(textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:) Optional("B48@0:8@16{_NSRange=QQ}24@40")</sup>
>   .
>   .
>   .

Comment: What are you planning to do with this information?

Comment: Right, I'm not sure if this will be possible in Swift because you would want to use invocations...

Comment: @jtbandes - To answer your first question, I'm trying to 'automate' the code in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41528359/2079103. As for your 2nd point - I deleted the other comments, so you can remove that if it makes sense to now ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is returned `objc_method_description.type` field?

- A method signature encoding scheme
- ... which includes an *obsolete stack offset representation*

In other words, to get a *usable* method signature encoding from the `type` field, just just extract the alpha-symbolic characters in left-to-right order discarding the digits.

Supporting documentation:

- [Objective-C Method Signature Type Encoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html)
- [Meaning of the numeric elements in signature encoding, explained by an Apple developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527385/how-are-the-digits-in-objc-method-type-encoding-calculated/11527925#11527925)
- [Playing around with Type Encodings](http://nshipster.com/type-encodings/)
- [class_addmethod](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/1418901-class_addmethod?language=objc) *(according to @Richard_J_Ross, this is the root of it)*
- [Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [Objective-C Runtime Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/1657527-objective_c_runtime)

---

Comment: As a general rule, documentation for this kind of stuff in the Objective-C APIs is done at the method level - in this case, class_addMethod: https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/1418901-class_addmethod?language=objc

Next time you find yourself on a goose chase, consider asking the question - what methods does this come from?

Comment: Thanks. Updated answer.