# What's the format for `objc_method_description.types` for swift blocks?

Tags: swift, objective-c, objective-c-runtime, method-signature

The Objective-C method encoding produced by the Swift compiler for swift methods with blocks seems to use syntax not documented anywhere.

For instance the method:

```swift
func DebugLog2(message: String) async -> String
```

has the method encoding:

> v32@0:8@"NSString"16@?<v@?@"NSString">24

and there are at least three characters (`"`, `<`, and `>`) not covered in the documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html

The `NSMethodSignature` class also doesn't like this encoding:

```objectivec
[NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:"\"NSString\"16@?<v@?@\"NSString\">24"];
```

results in:

> '+[NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:]: unsupported type encoding spec '"' in '"NSString"16@?<v@?@"NSString">24''

I tried looking through Swift's code, and it seems there's something called "extended method type encodings":

https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/c2fc7ee9e72e9a39854548e3202c667e4934dc65/test/IRGen/objc_methods.swift#L13-L14

but I got lost trying to figure out where in the Swift codebase the method type encoding is generated.

Related questions that don't answer this:

- [How to decipher "objc_method_description" from protocol method description list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41502199/how-to-decipher-objc-method-description-from-protocol-method-description-list)
- [What are the digits in an ObjC method type encoding string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491947/what-are-the-digits-in-an-objc-method-type-encoding-string)

Sample code:

```swift
decodeProto()

@objc
class TestClass : NSObject {
    @objc
    func DebugLog(message: String) -> String {
        print(message)
        return message
    }

    @objc
    func DebugLog2(message: String) async -> String {
        do {
            try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)
        } catch {}
        print(message);
        return message;
    }
}

func decodeProto() {
    var methodCount : UInt32 = 1
    let methodList = class_copyMethodList(TestClass.self, UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>(&methodCount))!
    for i in 0..<Int(methodCount) {
        let method = methodList[i];
        let desc = method_getDescription (method);
        let name = desc.pointee.name!
        let types = String(validatingUTF8: desc.pointee.types!)!
        print("Selector: \(name) Description: \(types)")
    }
}
```

prints:

```
Selector: DebugLog2WithMessage:completionHandler: Description: v32@0:8@"NSString"16@?<v@?@"NSString">24
Selector: DebugLogWithMessage: Description: @24@0:8@16
Selector: init Description: @16@0:8
```

---

But why do I need this?

I need to compute a maximum size for the stack frame, and in order to do that I parse the method encoding. The reason I need to compute the minimum size is because I intercept calls to objc_msgSend to add Objective-C exception handling before I call the actual objc_msgSend, so it's something like:

```objectivec
intercept_objc_msgSend (...) {
    @try {
        objc_msgSend (...);
    } @catch (NSException *ex) {
        handleException (ex);
    }
}
```

Note that it's not possible to create a generic interception method in C, so I've done it in assembly code. The generic interception code needs to allocate space for and copy the original arguments (stack frame), and in order to do that I parse the method encoding to figure out how big each argument is.

The count doesn't have to be exact, only a maximum is needed, so adding up the space required for all the arguments and allocating that much stack space works just fine, there's no need to subtract the size for any argument passed in registers.

Comment: So what is the problem? How you want to use that information?

Comment: I've added an addendum explaining the reason why.

Comment: Don't forget varargs, which are unbounded. But since you're already in assembly, I would think you'd check the frame pointer here to determine the size. Otherwise you have to consider all the padding issues. Is there a reason you're trying to compute it directly rather than use the FP-SP? (I haven't tried to build what you're building, so it's very possible I'm missing something obvious.) Also be sure to check Apple's slight alternations to the standard arm64 calling conventions: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/writing-arm64-code-for-apple-platforms

Comment: I'm sure you're aware, but just for anyone reading along it's worth noting that your code may leak memory and even violate preconditions since a lot of ObjC code is not exception-safe (exceptions are intended to terminate the program "soon" and much ObjC code relies on that fact; except in very controlled cases, there is no safe way to use `@catch` to continue the program). At a minimum you would want to to enable `-fobjc-arc-exceptions` since ARC is not exception-safe by default and would definitely leak memory. I'm guessing you have a good use, but others should be careful not to copy this.

Comment: (I'd love to hear more about what you're doing with this. Maybe trying to bridge ObjC exceptions over to C#? That would be very clean for Swift `throws`, but I worry the differences in intent between what ObjC and C# mean by "exception" would break that. Anyway; best of luck with your project.)

Comment: @RobNapier Yes, bridging ObjC exceptions over to C# is exactly what we're doing in https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios. Here's a document describing what we support: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/exception-marshaling. I know very well that ObjC exceptions are much more _exceptional_ than C# exceptions, but at some point we have to be pragmatic and deal with what we've got. Just terminating the process is not a very good user experience, for a number of reasons.

Comment: We don't really handle varargs at all, so that's not a problem at the moment. I hadn't thought about just computing FP-SP, but we also have to copy all the arguments into the new stack frame, so some understanding of each argument is nice (although I guess we could just copy the entire chunk of memory from A to B and hope for the best?)

Comment: "Not good user experience" needs to include "corrupting their persistent data" which is absolutely possible once you violate basic preconditions, which is what the majority of ObjC exceptions indicate has happened. I agree there may be debate on this topic, but recovering from arbitrary ObjC exceptions is something we've discussed in the Cocoa world for decades, and the answer we came to was "let it crash." Changing that long-forged decision is a big lift.

Comment: To the latter, "just copy the entire chunk of memory from A to B" is a mandatory starting point. But I think you'll eventually discover you **also** need to understand each argument, which is hard, and always subject to change. (And Apple absolutely does change how these things work, mercilessly, within anything allowed by their ABI, which is a lot.)

Comment: Yes, I agree corrupting data due to catching Objective-C isn't a good thing. However, the alternative may be worse... AppKit _already_ catches Objective-C exceptions and blithely ventures forth, which is another level of bad if there are managed frames on the stack. Converting them back/from managed exceptions and the native/managed code boundary makes managed developers actually able to figure out what's happening and do something about it.

Comment: Another painpoint we hit was during debugging - inspecting an object's properties shouldn't terminate the process, but inspecting properties often results in "selector not found" exceptions (in particular when running on an earlier OS version - inspecting any property only available in a later OS version will throw a "selector not found" exception).

Comment: At least with Swift the corruption problem seems to have been fixed!

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe the encoding format is publicly documented. You can work out most of it from the [ASTContext](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/ASTContext_8cpp_source.html#l08465) source. Mattt's [Type Encodings blog post](https://nshipster.com/type-encodings/) sums it up well:

> So what do we gain from our newfound understanding of Objective-C Type Encodings? Honestly, not that much (unless you’re doing any crazy metaprogramming).
>
> But as we said from the very outset, there is wisdom in the pursuit of deciphering secret messages.

And I agree, it's a worthy pursuit. Just don't expect this to be all that useful in Swift.

To answer this specific situation:

> v32@0:8@"NSString"16@?<v@?@"NSString">24

As you know from your previous research, [the numbers don't mean much](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527385/how-are-the-digits-in-objc-method-type-encoding-calculated/11527925#11527925), so we won't worry about those.

The syntax `@"..."` is an object with the class name given in quotes. You can find that in the `Type::ObjCObjectPointer` case:

```
 8501    S += '@';
 8502    if (OPT->getInterfaceDecl() &&
 8503        (FD || Options.EncodingProperty() || Options.EncodeClassNames())) {
 8504      S += '"';
 8505      S += OPT->getInterfaceDecl()->getObjCRuntimeNameAsString();
 8506      for (const auto *I : OPT->quals()) {
 8507        S += '<';
 8508        S += I->getObjCRuntimeNameAsString();
 8509        S += '>';
 8510      }
 8511      S += '"';
 8512    }
```

The syntax `@?<...>` is a block pointer, as detailed in the `Type::BlockPointer` case:

```
 8401  case Type::BlockPointer: {
 8402    const auto *BT = T->castAs<BlockPointerType>();
 8403    S += "@?"; // Unlike a pointer-to-function, which is "^?".
 8404    if (Options.EncodeBlockParameters()) {
 8405      const auto *FT = BT->getPointeeType()->castAs<FunctionType>();
 8406 
 8407      S += '<';
 8408      // Block return type
 8409      getObjCEncodingForTypeImpl(FT->getReturnType(), S,
 8410                                 Options.forComponentType(), FD, NotEncodedT);
 8411      // Block self
 8412      S += "@?";
 8413      // Block parameters
 8414      if (const auto *FPT = dyn_cast<FunctionProtoType>(FT)) {
 8415        for (const auto &I : FPT->param_types())
 8416          getObjCEncodingForTypeImpl(I, S, Options.forComponentType(), FD,
 8417                                     NotEncodedT);
 8418      }
 8419      S += '>';
 8420    }
 8421    return;
 8422  }
```

What this is encoding is the following:

```
- (void)m:(NSString *)s completion:(void (^)(NSString *))c;
```

This is how `async` methods are translated to ObjC: a completion handler is added that accepts the return value.

For fun, you can extend this to an `async throws` function:

```
func DebugLog2(message: String) async throws -> String
```

And the result will be:

```
v32@0:8@"NSString"16@?<v@?@"NSString"@"NSError">24
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
- (void)m:(NSString *)s completion:(void (^)(NSString *, NSError *))c;
```

(I should be clear when I say "equivalent" here, I don't mean it would literally be the same as calling `method_getTypeEncoding` on these methods. `method_getTypeEncoding` doesn't return extended encodings. You'd get `v32@0:8@16@?24` for both of these: a void-returning method that takes an object (@) and a block (@?). But these are the methods being described by the Swift encodings.)

As a side note, NSMethodSignature can definitely parse the result. You just changed it to an invalid string (you removed the return type):

```
const char *types = "v32@0:8@\"NSString\"16@?<v@?@\"NSString\">24";
NSMethodSignature *signature = [NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:types];
printf("%s\n", [signature getArgumentTypeAtIndex:3]);

// Outputs: @?<v@?@"NSString">
```